# Nim Game remove $1,3$ or $ 4$ matches

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

I was reading about variations of the nim game where 2 players remove matches from a pile of matchsticks.
In this variation players can remove $1,3$ or $4$ matches.
I can see that the player wins if the number of matches in the pile is:

```
{1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 17 ....}
```

and the player loses if the number of matches in the pile is:

```
{0, 2, 7, 9, 14, 16 ...}
```

It is not clear to me what is the pattern that indicates if the number of matches is a win.
I thought `4*2 = 8` (win) but also `4*2 + 1 = 9` (lose) so some multiple of the number of matches to remove is not a winning state.
What is the pattern here?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the version you're talking about? Like, about the rules.

Comment: >{1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 17 ....} Doesn't this look like following a difference of {2,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,...}
>{0, 2, 7, 9, 14, 16,...} follows {2, 5, 2, 5, 2,...}

Comment: @Mastermind817: Rules are each player is allowed to remove 1,3 or 4 matches from the pile. So if there is 1 match, player A removes 1 and player B loses. If there are 4 matches, player A removes 4 matches and player B loses. If there are 5 matches, player A removes 3 matches, player B is left with 2 matches from which can remove only 1 hence player A wins

Comment: Does this help?

  [1]: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180333/winning-strategy-for-a-matchstick-game?rq=1

Comment: @Mastermind817: how does that difference translate to determining from a specific number of matchsticks on the pile if A or B wins (assuming optimal play)?

Comment: @Mastermind817: The link you posted is about removing `[1..N]` matches. But in my case it is not `[1..4]` i.e. the full range since removing 2 matches is not an allowed move

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117610/discussion-between-mastermind817-and-jim).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ the losers are $\{2,7\}.$

Inductively assume that for
$\{1,2,3, \cdots, (7n-2), (7n-1), 7n\}$ the losers are precisely those numbers that are congruent to either 2 or 7, mod 7.

Consider the numbers $\{(7n+1), (7n+2), \cdots, (7n + 7)\}.$

(7n+1) can take 1, leaving (7n), so (7n+1) is a winner.

(7n+2) must leave (7n+1), (7n-1), (7n-2), which are all inductively assumed to be winners.  Therefore, (7n+2) is a loser.

By very similar reasoning, (7n+3) through (7n+6) are winners and (7n+7) is a loser.

Comment: `congruent to either 2 or 7, mod 7` means that n mod 7 = 2 or 7?

Comment: @Jim exactly.  Intended that positive integer $x$ is a loser if and only if $\{$either $x \equiv 2\pmod{7}$ or $x\equiv 7\pmod{7}\}.$

Comment: `(7n+2) must leave (7n+1), (7n-1), (7n-2), which are all inductively assumed to be winners.`. May be silly question but how do we formally prove that e.g. `7n - 2 mod 7 != 2`? I can see it by plugging some numbers but is this accepted?

Comment: @Jim Formally: for $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}, ~c \neq 0,$ by definition, $a \equiv b\pmod{c} \iff c | (a-b). ~ 7 | [(7n - 2) - (-2)]~$ and $~7 | [(-2) - 5].~$ Therefore, $~(7n-2) \equiv (-2) \equiv 5\pmod{7}~$ and by inductive assumption, all numbers $\leq (7n)$ that are congruent to 5 (mod 7) are *winners*.

Comment: `≡(mod)` this means that `a is congruent b mod C` but I don't understand the syntax next to `⟺`. Is that `c*abs((a - b) * 7)`? And how did `[(7−2)−(−2)]  and  7|[(−2)−5].` show up?

Comment: @Jim $c|(a-b)$ denotes that $c$ divides $(a-b)$ (**evenly without remainder**) which denotes that $(a-b)$ is a multiple of $c$.  For example, $7$ divides $([7n-2] - [-2])$ **because** $([7n-2] - [-2]) = 7n$, which is a multiple of $7$.  Similarly, $7|(2-2)$ because $(2-2) = 0$ and $0$ is a multiple of $7.$

Comment: @Jim My motivation for examining $[(7−2)−(−2)]$  and  $7|[(−2)−5]$ was simply an artificial way of emphasizing that $[7n-2] \equiv 5 \pmod{7}.$  I could have (instead) merely stated that $(7n-2) = (7[n-1] + 5)$ and then demonstrated that $(7[n-1] + 5) \equiv 5\pmod{7}.$  My **sole** point around $(7n-2)$ was to demonstrate as clearly as possible that $(7n-2) \equiv 5\pmod{7}.$

Comment: So if I got this right, the idea is that `7n - 2` and `-2` belong to the same class which is 5. And to prove that you used the fact that 7 evenly divides `-2 - 5`?

Comment: @Jim Yes exactly. I also used the fact that $7$ evenly divides $[(7n-2) - (-2)].$  The idea is that if $7$ evenly divides $r$ and $7$ evenly divides $s$, then $7$ evenly divides $(r + s)$.  Here, $\{[(7n-2) - (-2)] + [(-2) - (5)]\} = [(7n-2) - (5)].$

Comment: Last question: I thought that since 7mod2 = 2 then 7mod(-2) = 2 as well. But here I see that you uses 7mod(-2) = 5. Are there 2 ways to calculate the remainder? What is the proper way for negatives then?

Comment: @Jim First of all, it isn't 7mod2 = 2.  Instead it is $2 \equiv 2\pmod{7},$ **because** $7$ divides $(2-2) = 0$ evenly.  Remember, the definition is that $~a \equiv b\pmod{c} \iff c~$ divides $(a-b)$ evenly.  Although $7$ does **not** divide $[(-2) - (2)]$ evenly, $7$ **does** divide $[(-2) - (5)]$ evenly.

Comment: When I said `7 mod 2 = 2`, I had in mind the remainder of when dividing 7 with 2. And `7 mod -2 = 2` the remainder when dividing 7 with -2. Now I see you are using the equivalence classes which is confusing to me. So to figure out that `7 % -2 = 5` I should use the definition of congruence? Not do the division and check the remainder? That is the part I am confused

Comment: @Jim Yes, to determine what the equivalence class for an integer $x$ is $\pmod{7}$, you divide $x$ by $7$.  This will give you a quotient $Q$ and a remainder $R$, where $R \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}.$ Here, you should ignore the quotient $Q$ and conclude that $x$ belongs to the (congruency $\pmod{7}$ ) equivalence class represented by $R$.  Note that this means that $7$ will divide evenly $(x - R)$, which corresponds to the definition that I gave you, re $x\equiv R\pmod{7}.$

Comment: So if `x = -2` we have when dividing x by 7 that `Q = 0` and `R = |-2| = 2`. This means that x belongs to the equivalence class represented by `R = |-2|=2` which can be found due to the fact that 7 divides evenly `(x - R) = (-2 - (2)) = -4` which is obviously false. Where am I messing this up?

Comment: @Jim When $x = -2$ then $x \div 7 = (-1)$, with remainder $5$.  You never take the absolute value of the remainder.  Having a remainder of $(-2)$ is distinct from having a remainder of $(2)$.  The trick is to select $Q$ (in this case $Q=[-1]$, not $Q=0$) so that the remainder $R$ is an element of $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}.$

Comment: I see, so there are 2 ways to calculate the remainder then. Because doing `int x = -2; System.out.println(x % 7)` prints `-2`. So is the approach of not taking a negative remainder the mathematical approach or what?

Comment: The idea is to **first** define a set of equivalence classes.  In this case, since your working with modulo $7$, the natural specification is to have the equivalence classes be represented by $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}.$  Then, **after** the equivalence classes are defined, and you are dividing $x$ by $7$, you **must** determine $Q$ and $R$ such that $Q$ is an integer, and $R$ is an element of $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}.$  So the choice of $Q$ is **totally controlled** by the constraint that $R$ must be an element of $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}.$

Answer (score 1):

Let $b_k=1$ when $k$ is a winning number and $b_k=0$ otherwise. Doing the analysis the OP did somewhat further one quickly conjectures that
$$(b_k)_{k\geq0}=(0,1,0,1,1,1,1,\ldots)\ ,$$
where the $\ldots$ suppress a periodic pattern with period $7$. That this pattern is true for $0\leq k\leq 6$ we know from looking at the computed table.

It remains to set up an induction proof: For each of the seven remainders mod $7$ we  go  back the necessary steps and verify that everything suits. The inductive hypothesis is: The pattern is true for all $k≤7j−1$. The induction is with respect to $j$, and the base case is $j=1$.

Comment: So if n mod 7 is 0 or 2 is a losing state right? So if I understand it: `this pattern is true for 0≤≤6 ` is the inductive hypothesis. Then I pick a random k where 6n + 1 <= k <= 6n + 7 to prove it?